# Работа UNIX, домашняя работа, не работает как хотелось конструкция ls -il | grep -i 'di'

Tags: bash, unix

Итак, есть задание

> Вывести три первых элемента рекурсивного списка имен и атрибутов файлов в директории lab0, содержащих строчку "di", список отсортировать по убыванию даты изменения записи о файле, ошибки доступа перенаправить в файл в директории /tmp.

Не понимаю, как я могу связать команды `ls` и `grep`. Знаю что если написать `find . -name 'g*' -type f -ls` выйдет информация о файлах, с именами начинающимися на *g*, но с `grep` 
 `-ls` связать не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Задание - лютый треш... Но вообще вам нужно направить вывод одной программы в другой через стандартные потоки ввода вывода используя `|` (piping)

Answer (score 4):

Если все правильно понял, то команда такая:

```
grep -rl --null di lab0 2>/tmp/error.txt | xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %n %A" | sort -r | head -n3 | cut -d" " -f2-
```

Чтобы такое соорудить, нужно знать три вещи:

- что есть перенаправления потока данных из одной команды в другую или в файл (`|`, `>`), а без этого такую сложную задачу не решить
- знать подходящие команды, `find` тут не нужен, а `grep` может сам искать рекурсивно
- есть встроенная справка: `man grep`, `man stat`, ..., хотя я часть аргументов таки нашел через Гугл

Пройдемся по порядку, чтобы была понятна суть

```
grep -rl di lab0
```

`-r` - рекурсивно, `-l` - вернуть только список. у меня получился такой список:

```
lab0/lab/1/2/3/6.txt
lab0/lab/1/2/3/5.txt
grep: lab0/lab/1/2/3/100.txt: Отказано в доступе
lab0/lab/1/2/3/1.txt
lab0/lab/1/2/3/4.txt
lab0/lab/1/2/3/2.txt
lab0/lab/1/2/3/a b c.txt
```

### 2. получение даты модификации

для последующей сортировки нужно получить информацию о всех файлах в таком формате: `дата-модификации имя-файла`

`ls` не может вывести в таком формате, но есть команда `stat`

`man stat`:

> -c  --format=FORMAT
>
> use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT
>
> %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
>
> %n     file name
>
> %A     access rights in human readable form

Но напрямую `stat` не читает поток, `grep ... | stat ...` сделать не получится. Поэтому используем `xargs`:

```
grep -rl --null di lab0 2>/tmp/error.txt | xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %n %A"
```

тут:

- `2>/tmp/error.txt` - перенаправление ошибок в файл
- `--null` - выводить список файлов не через пробел, а через null-терминированные строки, иначе будет ошибка, если в имени файла есть пробел
- `-0` - уже для `xargx` означает читать файлы, перечисленные построчно, а не через пробел
- `xargs` уже вызывает `stat`

получилось так:

```
1581101904 lab0/lab/1/2/3/6.txt -rw-rw-r--
1581101904 lab0/lab/1/2/3/5.txt -rw-rw-r--
1581102146 lab0/lab/1/2/3/1.txt -rw-rw-r--
1581101904 lab0/lab/1/2/3/4.txt -rw-rw-r--
1581101904 lab0/lab/1/2/3/2.txt -rw-rw-r--
1581102859 lab0/lab/1/2/3/a b c.txt -rw-rw-r--
```

### 3. сортировка, лимит и удаление лишнего

```
| sort -r | head -n3 | cut -d" " -f2-
```

оставшийся "хвост" такой трубы читается так:

- обратная сортировка
- выбрать первые три строки
- вывести части, разбитые по пробелу, начиная со второй (удалить по пробелу дату модификации)